How to catch and fix a memory leakage?
I wrote a shell-like program and I have a memory leakage that I'm unable to fix.
in case of invalid_command && command1 || command2 (and it happens only in this case, everything else working perfectly) something in my function that contains command1 && command2 seems to not being freed.
When invalid_command return an error, it skips the attempt to run command1 (because of the way "&&" operator works) and runs command2, any ideas on what to do in order to solve this issue?
this is my problematic function (I've deleted lots of unrelated stuff to this issue in the following code)
void execute_user_command(char *command, runData *data, int saved_stderr, const char *error_file) {
    char *copy = strdup(command);
    char *args[MAX_ARGS + 1];  // Array to store command arguments
    int arg_count;
    int background = 0;
    char *sep;
    int status = 0;
    char *check_quotes = NULL;


    // Check for || operator
    sep = strstr(copy, "||");
    char *or_command = NULL;
    if (sep) {
        *sep = '\0';
        sep += 2;
        check_quotes = strdup(copy);
        status = 2;
        while (*sep == ' ') sep++;  // Skip spaces
        or_command = sep;
    }

    // Check for && operator
    sep = strstr(copy, "&&");
    if (sep) {
        *sep = '\0';
        sep += 2;
        check_quotes = strdup(copy);
        while (*sep == ' ') sep++;  // Skip spaces

        split_command(copy, args, &arg_count);
        // If the first command is a special command, handle it
        if (handle_special_commands(copy, data) != -1) {
            // If the second command is also a special command, handle it
            if (handle_special_commands(sep, data) == -1) {
                // If the second command is not a special command, execute it
                execute_user_command(sep, data, saved_stderr, error_file);
            }
        } else {
            // If the first command is not a special command, execute it
            if (execute_command(args, copy, background, error_file, data)) {
                check_matching_quotes(check_quotes, data);
                // If the second command is a special command, handle it
                if (handle_special_commands(sep, data) == -1) {
                    // If the second command is not a special command, execute it
                    execute_user_command(sep, data, saved_stderr, error_file);
                }
                // If the first command wasn't special and resulted in an error, don't execute the second command and skip to the third
            } else if (or_command) {
                if (handle_special_commands(or_command, data) == -1) {
                    execute_user_command(or_command, data, saved_stderr, error_file);
                }

            }
        }
        free(check_quotes);
        free(copy);

        return;
    }

    // Split the command into arguments
    split_command(copy, args, &arg_count);

    if (arg_count == 0) {
        free(copy);
        return;  // Ignore empty commands
    }

    if (arg_count > MAX_ARGS) {  // Command plus 4 arguments is allowed
        fprintf(stderr,"ERR: Too many arguments\n");
        free(copy);
        return;  // Skip commands with more than 4 arguments
    }


    if (arg_count > 0) {
        if (status == 1 || status == 0) {
            execute_command(args, command, background, error_file, data);
        } else {
            if (!execute_command(args, copy, background, error_file, data) &&
                handle_special_commands(or_command, data) == -1) {
                execute_user_command(or_command, data, saved_stderr, error_file);
            } else {
                check_matching_quotes(check_quotes, data);
            }
        }
    }

    free(check_quotes);
    free(copy);
}


I tried debugging it, which isn't so simple since it a recursive function.
and I ran Valgrind multiple times and I'll share some of the results here:
input:
a && b || echo 3

result:
definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks

input:
aa && b || echo 3

result:
definitely lost: 9 bytes in 1 blocks

input:
aa && bb || echo 3

result:
definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 blocks

input:
aa && bb || echo 33

result:
definitely lost: 10 bytes in 1 blocks

Valgrind:
==8988== (A Number Depends on input as shown above) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==8988==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8988==    by 0x491558E: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==8988==    by 0x10AEE9: execute_user_command (in /home/student/CLionProjects/ShellLike)
==8988==    by 0x10A0A7: process_input (in /home/student/CLionProjects/ShellLike/main)
==8988==    by 0x10B512: main (in /home/student/CLionProjects/ShellLike1/main)


Memory returned by strdup() needs to be free()'d.

You seem to assign the result of  strdup to  check_quotes multiple times without free() in between.

check_quotes = strdup(copy); called twice but only freed once !

@Lundin and .@ticktalk Thanks, fixed it !
